# Windows 7 - Firefox - Font Displayed Strangely

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox, fonts

[image]

The p's and b's in the above image are strange, relative to the other letters. They are more-bold or stretched a bit horizontally. This is viewing wikipedia in firefox on windows 7. Even the text on serverfault appears this way... some letters appear almost bold because they get stretched horizontally a bit.

This is a completely default installation of Windows 7 and Firefox... really don't know what's going on here.

What's going on here and how can I fix it? This is very annoying to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Turns out I was missing a couple of fonts. You need Arial regular and also Verdana regular and bold. I just moved these from a Vista fonts folder on another PC to the fonts folder in Windows 7 on my PC and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The best first solution would be to use the ClearType tuner.  It works on all Windows versions including Windows 7 and may address your dilema.

http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/tuner/tune.aspx

Comment: Windows 7 has this integrated. Just search for "ClearType" on the start menu.

Comment: I worked with this for a while... it didn't help. My other 3 monitors look just fine too.

Answer (score 1):

go to **Tools> Options> Content> Font & Color> Advanced** And common fonts to fonts such as Tahoma or Times New Roman change
you can see other ways in this url:

**English Language:** [http://sinac.ws/](http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?hl=en&prev=/search?q=sinac.ws&hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=d4t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&prmd=ivns&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=fa&u=http://sinac.ws/font-problem-in-windows-7-and-firefox/&usg=ALkJrhhR4_abkI1JWZHEwdOzWpkt2kzyLQ)

**Persian Language:** http://sinac.ws/font-problem-in-windows-7-and-firefox/