# Ugly fonts in Firefox on some sites, not in Chromium, why?

Tags: firefox, fonts

After switching back to Firefox I noticed that a few sites I frequently visit don't look that good, the fonts are jagged and sometimes it makes it harder to read the text. I don't have this problem when visiting the site using Chromium. This is a screenshot of how gitlab.com looks, not pretty:

[image: Gitlab.com in FF and Chromium]

Why is that, and more importantly how do I fix Firefox to be pretty too?

Comment: It is strange. On Chrome 30.0.1599.69, it does not use the font specified by the developers. `font-family: "Open Sans","Helvetica Neue","Helvetica",Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;` However, on Firefox 22.0, it used "Open Sans" to display the text. If you removed that CSS statement by using "Inspect Element", you can see the effect.

Comment: Chrome blocked access to font Open Sans. http://i.stack.imgur.com/yH3Un.png

Comment: That's a bit strange indeed.  So it seems the font choice of the site developers is to blame.  Well, not much to do about that part then.  I wonder if that also causes the Outlook Webinterface pages to look similarly ugly in the font department.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ugly fonts on several Google sites in Firefox and Chrome](http://superuser.com/questions/612307/ugly-fonts-on-several-google-sites-in-firefox-and-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same problem with Google fonts (specially Google Spreadsheets) using Firefox. What it worked for me was the next:

1. Open in Firefox the document or URL that is displaying "ugly fonts". Make sure to open a Firefox window on each monitor/screen that you have available. In my case I have the display of my laptop and 2 external monitors.
2. Open the link [Refresh Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings)
3. Click on the button "Refresh Firefox".
4. In the popup window, confirm clicking the button "Refresh Firefox".
5. Your Firefox configuration and addons will be reset to default, don't worry techie guys: All your bookmarks and passwords will be saved.
6. Wait until Firefox closes itself and gets open again.
7. Once The Firefox is refreshed you are good to go, check again the page with ugly fonts and the problem should be gone.

Other option insteas the link showed in the step #2 is go to url [about:support](http://about:support). The button "Refresh button" is on the up right corner.

Answer (score 0):

It could have happen that you enabled the page zoom holding CMD or CTRL and scrollwheel. That can make even images look jaggy. Try from menu selecting View > Zoom > Reset.